# Insert an array into another PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have two arrays - cards and tokens and I want to put one into another:

```
{
    "cards": [
    {
        "CardNumber": "xxxxxx******xxxx",
        "Holder": "EUEUEUEUEUEU",
        "ExpirationDate": "xx/xxxxx"
    },
    {
        "CardNumber": "xxxxxx******xxxx",
        "Holder": "EU",
        "ExpirationDate": "xx/xxxxx"
    }
]
}

{
"tokens": [
    {
        "token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    {
        "token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
]
```

How to insert the second array into the first as follows:

```
{
"cards": [
    {
        "token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "CardNumber": "xxxxxx******xxxx",
        "Holder": "EUEUEUEUEUEU",
        "ExpirationDate": "xx/xxxxx"
    },
    {
        "token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "CardNumber": "xxxxxx******xxxx",
        "Holder": "EU",
        "ExpirationDate": "xx/xxxxx"
    }
]
}
```

I'm getting cards array with the following code. $token return the token values:

```
    foreach ($token_values as $token) {
        $request[] = getCards($merchantId, $merchantKey, $token);
    }
    $arrayJSON['cards'] = $request;
    echo json_encode($arrayJSON);
```

Comment: What format are these "arrays" in? They don't appear to be valid PHP. Please clarify your intent.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot some details. Edited!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to just add the `token` value inside your `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($token_values as $token) {
    $request[] = array_merge(array('token' => $token), getCards($merchantId, $merchantKey, $token));
}
```